# Simplifying an expression written as the sum of three fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Specifically, I don't know what to do first given the following expression:

$$
\frac{4x - 2}{6} - \frac{2 - x}{4} + \frac{x + 3}{3}
$$

So I think of it as $\frac 16(4x-2) - \frac 14(2-x) + \frac 13(x+3)$?

That just gives me more fractions.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You need to put parentheses around what are numerators, and what are denominators of each fraction. There's no way of knowing, otherwise, what is dividing what.

Comment: Do you mean $4x-\frac{2}{6-\frac{2-x}{4+\frac{x+3}{3}}}$?

Comment: Not really. I have edited the question @PaulSundheim

Answer (score 1):

Find the common denominator first, noting that the least common multiple of $6, 4, 3$ is $12: $12 = 2\times 6 = 3\times 4 = 4\times 3$. This way, you can write the entire expression as *one* fraction:

$$\frac{4x - 2}{6} - \frac{2 - x}{4} + \frac{x + 3}{3} = \frac{2(4x-2) - 3(2-x) + 4(x+3)}{12}$$

Now expand the factors in the numerator on the right-hand side, and then simplify (add [or subtract] the factors of $x$, and do the same for the constants. Doing this will give you a final result of the form $\dfrac{ax + b}{12}$, where $a, b$ are nonzero constants.